# Netstat switches

Tags: netstat

I was monitoring network connections using Netstat and came across `netstat -tlnp`.  I was wondering what this is, what it does, and how the command works. I have checked the netstat man pages for my distro however, I cannot seem to find the entire syntax. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: As a new learner to information security, I encourage you to develop your google searching skill. I googled "netstat tlnp" and got several hits explaining each switch.

Comment: Netstat is not a security tool, and the switches do not provide security functions. Yes, you are trying to use the tool for security purposes, but this is a OS command used for a variety of purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Netstat -tlnp` is the netstat application with arguments:

- `-t`: Show only the TCP protocol
- `-l`: Show only listening sockets
- `-n`: Show numerical addresses instead of attempting to resolve the
  hostname
- `-p`: Show the PID of the program that is associated with
  that socket

So combined you are running netstat that will show listening TCP sockets and display the IP address and PID of the socket.

From the [netstat man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/netstat)

*Edit:*

The reason for using each argument:

`-t` is useful if you do not want to see all protocol sockets (you can use `-u` for UDP)

`-l` cleans up the output so that you will only see the sockets with the state `LISTENING` instead of all states (closed, established etc)

`-n` will display the IP address and port number, this makes the results display quicker as netstat will not attempt to perform a hostname lookup which can take time.

`-p` can help you identify which running process is attached to the socket and listening on the port